# How to redirect with previously flashed data?

Tags: laravel

How can I forward the previously flashed data with `Redirect`. I could use `Session::reflash()` or I could take the data from the session and flash it again but I am looking something like:

```
Redirect::route('index')
    ->with('message', 'hello')
    ->withReflash();
```

Is there something like `withReflash()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [`RedirectResponse`](https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/master/RedirectResponse.php) class, there is no any similar method, so you'll still need to reflash session data manually with `->reflash()`.

Comment: yep then I will go with that.